# laravel create eloquent on mass assignment $request->all() a single field is always null

Tags: laravel, eloquent

****i have used create eloquent and i used massassignment($request->all()) for saving data but only "feede_quantity" column is always null. I have print the request->all() and its showing all the form data including "feeder_quntity" but while creating its value is null. i have given my model,controller and blade code and also added the database image. Please tell me what is wrong here. Thank you****

```
**My Model** 

protected $table = 'ebay_accounts';

protected $fillable = ['id','developer_id','feeder_quantity','account_name',
                   'authorization_token','access_token','refresh_token','session_id','expiry_date'];
protected $dates = ['deleted_at','created_at','updated_at'];




**My controller**
public function storeAuthorization(Request $request){

    $result = EbayAccount::create(['developer_id' => $request->developer_id,'feeder_quantity' => 5]);
    $account_site = EbayAccount::find($result->id);
    $account_site->sites()->attach($request->site_id);
    return redirect('ebay-account-list')->with('success','account created successfully');
}



**myblade file**
<div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
            <label for="feeder_quantity" class="col-md-3 col-form-label ml-sm-25 mr-sm-25 ml-xs-25 mr-xs-25 required">Feeder Quantity</label>
            <div class="col-md-7 ml-sm-25 mr-sm-25 ml-xs-25 mr-xs-25">
                <input id="feeder_quantity" type="number" class="form-control @error('feeder_quantity') is-invalid @enderror" name="feeder_quantity" value="" maxlength="80" onkeyup="Count();" required autocomplete="name" autofocus>
                <span id="display" class="float-right"></span>
                @error('feeder_quantity')
                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                                         <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                                    </span>
                @enderror
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        </div>
**database table value is always empty for feeder_quantity**
```

[image]

Comment: Why there is value=" " in your input field? Just remove value=" " attribute and save again. also check dd($request->all()) if you get feeder_quantity value .

Comment: value="" because initially there is no value which is not the problem. and my dd($request->all()) value is `{"_token":"xzBwsfbrbF0jxAlHBwEmOnGKKHl9FO2ccxn0fc3J","account_name":"test","feeder_quantity":"5","site_id":["3"],"developer_id":"1"}`. i hope i will help you to understand the problem

Comment: What is your data type of feeder_quantity?

Comment: data type is integer

Comment: Can you try removing nullable for feeder_quantity in table and do submit and see what error you get? Because code seem to be good.

Comment: all feeder_quantity column values became 0 and didn't give any error. I didn't set any default value for feeder_quantity only changed to nullable.

Comment: Did you remove nullable from table?

Comment: all though everything seems ok, but still its not working :( !!!!!!

Comment: yes I have changed it to not nullable and then it happened